# Thread.Abort and App crash

Tags: .net, multithreading, clr, finalize

all
I found something wierd with my program

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Threading;
namespace TestCrash
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      /*Console.WriteLine(typeof(SqlInt32));*/
      var h = new Holder();
      h.Test();
      Console.WriteLine("TestHolder");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
  public class Holder
  {
      private Thread t;
      private void Work()
      {
          Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
      }
      ~Holder()
      {
          t.Abort();
      }
      public void Test()
      {
          t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
          t.IsBackground = true;
          t.Start();
      }
  }
```

This program terminates normally, however, if I **uncomment the fisrt code line** in Main which prints type of 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32', the program will crash when exit, and the windows event tells me that 'Access Violation' (0xc0000005)

```
Faulting application name: TestCrash.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x52b0189a
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5be02b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000159ad
Faulting process id: 0x1f20
Faulting application start time: 0x01cefb129f0bf5e8
Faulting application path: C:\yuanf\Flx\Source\TestCrash\bin\Debug\TestCrash.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: ddf78d96-6705-11e3-bafd-005056b80090
```

I found it has something to do with the thread abort, but can anyone explain why abort the 'Work' thread in the finalizer will cause the crash, while in other threads this will work well?

After some experiments, I found instead of printing 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32', any code that can introduce loading of the System.Data.dll will make this program terminate abnormally. How does it matter?

**To be noted, according to my tests, the crash happens only with .NET 4.0 on windows 2008R2, or win 7. With other version of .NET like 3.5 or 4.5, or OS like Windows XP, it terminates normally.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the crash not occur if you comment out the call to `t.Abort()`? You probably shouldn't be calling `Abort` there anyway. Accessing other objects inside of finalizers is a somewhat dicey proposition.

Comment: I also believe the abort will affect, and it does work if I remove the thread abort in the finalizer. However, the 'Holder' code is in a library which I can't change, and to my suprise, the load of System.Data.dll from my code affects the execution behavior too